# Book identification: assassin uses surrogate bodies to hunt targets on multiple planets

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a book about an agent who is a trained assasin. He is sent to four different planets to kill a target, but for each job his mind is put into a surrogate body before being sent planetside. One of the planets is a place called "Chavon" I think and in another of the books he is temporarily turned into a dinosaur-type creature through magic.

It’s a brilliant series and I would be interested if anyone can recall what it was called as I wish to get it as a birthday present for my sister.

Comment: Do you remember what year you read it, and/or what year it was published?  Do you remember what the cover looked like at all, or about how many books were in the series?  It sounds like an interesting series; I hope someone around here knows the answer, because I'm curious to check it out.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: You read too few internet forums if you haven't seen worse than "science fiction".  That one at least tells the body swap is done in a science fiction way, rather than a fantasy magic way, which I wouldn't guess from the content otherwise, especially not from "dinosaur-type creature through magic".

Comment: @b_jonas: well, I mean worst question title on *this site* ever. (Stack Exchange is pointedly not a forum; we demand better.)

Answer (score 6):

I read this book and its companions when I was younger; It's a series of four books by Jack Chalker called The Four Lords of the Diamond. You might be able to get them on Amazon. You're remembering the third book "Charon: A Dragon at the Gate"

The four Lords of the Diamond are prisoners on four planets in a solar system that is used as a prison because the planets have a symbiotic organism that infects all who are on the planets and will kill anyone infected if they leave the system.

This parasite infects everything and can communicate amongst itself, no matter what is infected with it. On one planet this communication allows someone who is more willful and in control of themselves to use the symbionts to change shape, similar to magic. On another planet it allows people to swap bodies.

The agent is on a ship outside the system and is using four bodies sent to each planet, to flush out a contact that is dealing with aliens and planning an invasion. On one planet, his surrogate body is morphed into a creature, by the bad guy in order to hamper his investigation.

Very interesting idea for the series, and even though the same agent is "present" on each of the four worlds, the stories do not unfold the same way in each book. Environment and experiences influence each individual agent differently on each planet.

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? Specifically, can you add some quotes and references to show *why* you think your answer is correct? Show your work, as my schoolteachers always said.

Comment: Edited to expand on my original answer.